# Visio Drag Events Out of Order

Tags: vba, drag, visio

Working in Visio, I'm seeing a strange behavior. When dropping the first shape from our stencil onto the page, we do a bit of processing, which takes about 10 seconds. On some machines (typically slower machines or faster ones that are working on another exe simultaneously) we find that after that 10 second processing, if you move the mouse, we get a duplicate shape dropped on the page; the same as the first master dropped on the page.

I was able to 'see' this happen using the Visio Event Viewer from the SDK. What seems to happen is we get the MouseMove events for /dragbegin, /dragenter, a bunch of /dragover events, and then /drop, and then a ShapeAdded event for our shape, and then our processing happens.

When I move the mouse again, I get another set of /dragbegin /dragenter and /drop events, and the master gets added again. The very weird part is that the event number index for the second /dragbegin event is two lower than the first /dragbegin event, even though thousands of events have happened. So the event numbering goes from 9xxx to 775, then back to 9xxx+1.

I have a feeling this is a very strange bug in Visio, but I'm thinking I can mitigate it if I can cancel that mousemove /dragbegin event. However, I don't see anything in the SDK for how to know that a mousemove event is a /dragbegin event. The Event Viewer seems to know, but I'm wondering how to figure that out.

Comment: Are you embedding Visio in your app? Or how is this being used?

Comment: The app is a Visio VSS stencil with embedded VBA code. There is another stencil from which the master is dropped.  Oddly, if I revert to an older version of the VBA VSS stencil, the issue does not occur.  But I have looked at the code changes between the versions and there is nothing related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767482(v=office.15).aspx

shows how to set up event monitoring using Visio's AddAdvise method, and get a categorization of what type of MouseMove event is occurring.

Using this method and logging /drop events, it seems that Visio is passing the same event multiple times under the low-memory conditions, and so preventing the problem includes blocking the event when the same event ID is encountered.